# How can we programmatically determine whether Java is installed on a Windows system?

Tags: java, tomcat

How can I write a program to detect whether Java is installed on a Windows machine?  I need to know because if it is not installed, then I have to install it using an embedded Tomcat.

Comment: Program to detect Java? Certainly, you wouldn't write in Java. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect whether client machine is already has installed version of JRE or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395768/how-to-detect-whether-client-machine-is-already-has-installed-version-of-jre-or-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is through the browser.
You can use or see how [this official Verify Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre&try=1) page detects Java availability and version from inside a browser.

LE: For some explained code and examples you can also check http://javatester.org/.

Comment: @pmad check the source of the page, it has nice comments and such. Just scroll the first 1k?! lines of white space.. and you'll get to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

- See whether the environment variables `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` exist and point at an existing directory with a `bin` subdirectory
- See whether the system `PATH` contains any directory in which there is a `java.exe`

In both cases you can additionally try to run the java executable with the `-version` command line option and check the output.

Comment: just i have to run my batch file it will detect the java installation and if not install it. how it happens??

Comment: @pmad - *you* have to *write* your batch file to do what @Michael says above.

Comment: @Stephen- To Check the Java Installation

Answer (score 0):

Just write a small script / batch file to execute `java` , if java is not installed, it'll throw an error, else if its installed it would give `usage`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program to check Windows registry. There should be paths to different java versions under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft.

Obviously this should be done in something else than java.